# How to generate specific random string in QuickCheck?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

In Haskell's QuickCheck, how to generate a string such that it contains only the characters ‘S’ and ‘C’, and the position of ‘S’ and ‘C’ is random?

For example: "SCCS", "SSSS", "CCCC", "CSSCCS", ""

My use case is this:

I have two functions `countCAndS :: String -> (Int, Int)` and `countCAndS' :: String -> (Int, Int)`. They have the same type signature. I'd like to write a QuickCheck property such that I can pass the same string to these two different functions and check if the outputs are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QuickCheck provides a flurry of combinators for that, it's super easy and very elegant:

```
prop_CountersEqual = 
  forAll csString $ \s -> countCAndS s == countCAndS' s

csString :: Gen String
csString = listOf $ elements "CS"
```

It's also trivial to expand your dictionary, should you need it.

Comment: Thanks. I like your solution better. Feels very elegant, and it has the minimum knowledge required to understand how it works.

Answer (score 6):

Let your property take a list of booleans and convert them to cs and ss.

```
prop_CountersEqual :: [Bool] -> Bool
prop_CountersEqual bs = countCAndS css == countCAndS' css where
    css = map (\b -> if b then 'C' else 'S') bs
```

If you need this frequently, you may want to define a new type with a suitable `Arbitrary` instance.

```
newtype CAndS = CAndS String
instance Arbitrary CAndS where
    arbitrary = CAndS . map (\b -> if b then 'C' else 'S') <$> arbitrary
```

Then you can write your properties as e.g.

```
prop_CountersEqual' :: CAndS -> Bool
prop_CountersEqual' (CAndS css) = countCAndS css == countCAndS' css
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to define the Arbitrary instance:

```
newtype CAndS = CAndS String
instance Arbitrary CAndS where
  arbitrary = CAndS <$> listOf (elements "CS")
```

Besides testing a function against a reference solution, you could test that the sum of `'C'`s and `'S'`es is the same as the length of the string:

```
prop_CountersAddUp :: CAndS -> Bool
prop_CountersAddUp (CAndS css) = length css == cs + ss
  where (cs, ss) = countCAndS css
```

If the string is supposed to accept input that has characters other than `'C'`s and `'S'`es (but not count them), you should perhaps create a generator that generates all kinds of characters, but with a higher probability of `'C'` and `'S'`:

```
newtype CAndS = CAndS String
instance Arbitrary CAndS where
  arbitrary = CAndS <$> listOf (frequency [ (1, return 'C')
                                          , (1, return 'S')
                                          , (2, arbitrary) ])
```

Or you might generate a string that is annotated with the right answer:

```
newtype CAndS = CAndS (String, Int, Int)
instance Arbitrary CAndS where
    arbitrary = CAndS <$> sized (\n -> do
      cs <- choose (0, n)
      let ss = n - cs
      css <- shuffle (replicate cs 'C' ++ replicate ss 'S')
      return (css, cs, ss))
```

So you can test it:

```
prop_CountersEqual :: CAndS -> Bool
prop_CountersEqual (CAndS (css, cs, ss)) = cs == cs' && ss == ss'
  where (cs', ss') = countCAndS css
```